# upgrade lubuntu without erasing disk

Tags: lubuntu, uefi, usb-installation, boot-partition, calamares

(see solution at the end of this post)

I have my hard drive partitioned in 2: one for OS (lubuntu 18.10) and the other for my data. I want to do a 'fresh upgrade' to version 19.04. So I created a bootable USB with `lubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso`.

The problem is that I don't see the option (as it used to be) to select the partition where to install lubuntu. The install app shows correctly both partitions, but the options I have are deleting them or creating new ones. I just want to override (ie erase and install lubuntu 19.04 in) the 18.10 partition, without touching the partition with my data. Does it make sense?
I know this is not crazy, because exactly this option was in the installer when I installed 18.10 and exactly due to that is that I organized my disk as mentioned (so I don't have to erase [and then populate again with my data] the disk every time I upgrade Lubuntu).

I don't want dual boot or anything 'strange', I only want to have Lubuntu 19.04 in one partition while keeping the other partition with my data.

Edit1: I am aware of the instructions in the manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html). But even when I tried to follow them, it is not easy for a beginner as there is no explanation on how to edit a partition. (e.g. Should I mark the flag? Or any other flags? What is the meaning of the other options? etc.)

Edit2: I think I am much better informed now. Just in case, I am showing here exactly what I see and I would like to know if my reasoning is right: 1) these are the options I have when trying to install Lubuntu 19.10: 
[image]

2) This is how I see my HD from the installer (the bigger partition is my data): 
[image]

3) when I click 'Edit' with the current Lubuntu partition selected, I see this: 
[image]

4) so please advice me are this options the appropriated ones to install Lubuntu 19.10 over my current Lubuntu, **and leave my data partition untouched**?: 
[image]

**Edit3 (solution)**: After trying different options, I discovered that if I boot the ISO using UEFI boot option then Lubuntu installator offers the option to install over a previous installation without touching anything else. The original post was originated because I chose the "normal" boot from USB option (since I don't even know what UEFI means I didn't want to play with that, I just assumed that booting from USB would be all I needed). Thus, now I learned that booting a USB with or without the UEFI option **makes a difference** for the installer. Problem solved. Thanks everybody!

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about flags, if it was me, I'd use "*Manual Partitioning*", select my current partitions ensuring "Format" was unticked. It'll cause the installer to take note of your software, erase system directories, install, then add-back your additional packages (if available in new release) without touching your data (unless you have format ticked - don't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Backup! Backup!! Backup!!!

Please make backups (two or three) of your important data before you try any of this. Make backups in two or three different external drives.

## Select Manual Partitioning

As others have already said. In Lubuntu it is called **Manual Partitioning** in Ubuntu it is **Something Else**.

## Select the partition containing the OS

As you have done in the picture below, select `/dev/sda` assuming that is the Ubuntu system partition mounted as `/`.

[image]

1. under **Content** select the **Format** button (as above).

**Note:** This will erase everything in your `/home/$USER` folder unless it is in the second partition. If you want to keep your documents, music, photos in the `/home/$USER` folder then select **keep** button. If you decide to format the system partition you can always restore the contents of the `/home/$USER` folder from backups.

2. Select **File System** `ext4` (as above).
3. Select **Mount Point** `/` (as above).
4. Leave Flags as is. No special flag are needed.

Click OK.

## Make sure your data partition is untouched.

1. under **Content** select the **Keep** button (This is the important part).

If you had used `/home` as the mount point of your data partition in the existing installation, then:

2. Select **Mount Point** `/home` (**Don't do this unless you are sure you have been using the second partition as your** `/home`).

You may not have to edit your second partition details unless you had `/home` there. If so, you can hit **Cancel** and keep everything as is for `/dev/sda2`.

Click **Next** at the bottom right of the screen and continue with the installation.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In the installer, select "Manual" (Lubuntu uses a different installer. In the regular Ubuntu installer, you would choose "Something Else"). This brings you to a screen where you can assign the different partitions yourself. Just have your Lubuntu installed on your current "lubuntu 18.10" partition (have that mounted to / and have it reformatted), and do *not* couple your data disk. This will install the full system on that partition, and leave your data disk alone. After installation, you can then have the data partition automatically mount during startup on a location of your choice by adding it to /etc/fstab.

Comment: Thanks. There is no 'Something Else' option. Just two options: 'Erase disk' or 'Manual' (where you see the partitions). In this 2nd option you can edit/delete partitions, but there are several options which are not friendly for a beginner..

Comment: "*Manual Partitioning*" is what `calamares` (installer used by Lubuntu 18.10 up) refers to where old `ubiquity` refered to "Something else". (`ubiquity` was used by 18.04 & earlier; and other flavors).   Yes different, but achieves the same thing (in a nicer way I feel)

Comment: I will indeed reflect that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I'd use "**Manual Partitioning**"
[image]

*Picture from the manual page you already referenced, but **please select Manual Partitioning** not what is shown*

Select your existing partitions, plus **ensure** "*Format*" is *unticked*.

It'll cause the installer to take note of your software, erase system directories, install, then add-back your additional packages (*if available in new release*) without touching your data (unless you have format ticked).

This method can be used to skip releases (ie. *I'd recommend you use 19.10 unless you want to repeat this process next month, standard (non-LTS) releases require release-upgrade every 6-9 months*)